# Using raw value-expressions in UPDATE with jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

This is the query I am trying to execute:

```
UPDATE TABLE users SET metadata = metadata - 'keyA' - 'keyB'
    WHERE <condition>;
```

Here, `metadata` is of type `jsonb` and the `-` operator removes a key from the JSON object. However, when I do this in jooq:

```
this.ctx.update(Tables.USERS)
    .set(Tables.USERS.METADATA, "metadata-'keyA'-'keyB'")
    .where(<condition>)
    .execute();
```

I get an error saying that the `value` is a `CHARACTER VARYING` and not `JSONB`, which I am guessing is because the query is being created with a bind value, and then entire string is being trying to be inserted rather than as an expression.

How do I execute this value-expression in jooq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're passing to the set method:

```
"metadata-'keyA'-'keyB'"
```

... is not an expression that is directly injected into the resulting SQL string. It's a bind variable of type String (i.e. `VARCHAR`). The easiest way forward would be to resort to using "plain SQL":

```
.set(USERS.METADATA, field(
     "{0} - {1} - {2}", 
     USERS.METADATA.getDataType(),
     USERS.METADATA, val("keyA"), val("keyB")
))
```

For more information related to using "plain SQL" with jOOQ, please refer to this section of the manual:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql