# Using jsonb_set in update with jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I have a sql query for updating a `status` value in a `data` column of type
`jsonb` in Postgresql that looks like this:

```
update sample
set updated = now(),
    data = jsonb_set(data, '{status}', jsonb 'CANCELLED', true)
where id = 11;
```

I need to translate that to a working jOOQ query in my Kotlin project ... I
have this so far:

```
jooq.update(Tables.SAMPLE)
        .set(Tables.SAMPLE.UPDATED, OffsetDateTime.now())
        .set(Tables.SAMPLE.DATA, field("jsonb_set(data, '{status}', jsonb '\"CANCELLED\"', true)"))
        .where(Tables.SAMPLE.ID.eq(id))
        .execute()
```

But the second `set` fails with *None of the following functions can be called with the
arguments supplied* error message... What is the correct signature of `set`
that I can use here?

I am basing my jOOQ syntax on the answer that Lukas Eder provided in [Using raw value-expressions in UPDATE with jooq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250835)

Comment: Why did you wrap `CANCELLED` in `"CANCELLED"`?

Comment: That's a great question ... I didn't even realize it until you pointed that out. It was an oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `UPDATE` statement, you have to match data types in your `SET` clause on both sides. I.e. `SAMPLE.DATA` is of type `Field<T>`, so the expression you're setting it to must also be of type `Field<T>`.

I'm assuming that `SAMPLE.DATA` is a `Field<JSONB>`, so it will be sufficient to write

```
.set(SAMPLE.DATA, field("json_set(...)", JSONB.class))
```

Notice that jOOQ 3.12 has introduced this `JSONB` type. In previous versions, lacking any out-of-the-box jOOQ representation for `JSON` and `JSONB` types, the jOOQ code generator may have generated a `Field<Object>` type for your `SAMPLE.DATA` column, in case of which your statement would have compiled.

Comment: It works exactly as you described, Thank you!  Just had to match with the correct type of the column.